# What is exact mean of Generic application in .net?

Tags: generics

So many times I found the question, by my team members we have to develop Generic Application either windows or Web. but what is its exact means?

Edited:-
Also If I want to develop such application then which design pattern will be best approach ? I am sure it should be on situation , but I want to know the scenarios in which we can use particular design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It means that features of the application might be applied to variations of the immediate requirement without or with minimal reprogramming.

It could imply that your team members have aspirations to create a market for the application, selling the same software to a variety of customers.

Or it could mean that they read about this generic stuff in an architecture magazine and now every problem looks like it needs a generic approach.

An alternative to consider is simply avoid the effort that goes into making something generic, with the idea of shipping sooner, with less risk, and with reduced maintenance costs.  [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it).

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you are talking about a way of developing an application. There is indeed a generic abroach which is more or less understood as the application is configurable and extentionable by configuration or metadata. Making something "generic" usualy means it can be used in more than one context and does not depend on "hardwired" dependencies.